# Moving to next slide after completion of animation which requires MouseClick (PowerPoint)

Tags: animation, microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

I'm working with a Presentation and I have some problems...

Before asking them I'd like to show up objects/element of slide I'm working on:

[image: My Slide]

I've added some elements in a slide and I'd like do something like this:

1. The slide is looped with *PlayButton* with animation of *'Spin'* and its being repeated until next mouse click
2. Viewer of presentation clicks Mouse Button and *Object 1 : GIF Cat* along with *Object 2 : Text CTS* should disappear
3. This should be followed by *'Grow and Shrink'* animation of Play Button
4. Then the slide show should be proceeded to next slide

So, here are the applied animations:

[image: AnimationPanel]

Finally and ultimately my question is how to advance the slide show to next slide after the last animation (of whole slide) has been played... The last animation plays but doesn't proceeds to next slide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go to the "Slide Show" menu and then click on "Transitions..."

[image]

After that you can now choose slide transition which you wish to apply when your slide appear.

Now you just need to uncheck "on mouse click" and check "After" now you will need to define time in seconds for your slide transition.

Comment: Actually, the object is looped until next mouse click so the timeout will ruin the show

Comment: @HackerBoy you could do one thing if you like... at next slide for 1st object in animation choose option "After Previous". So when you click mouse button the next slide will appear along with 1st object and that would look good as next slide won't just be empty, give it a try. Apologies if my suggestion are not useful for you.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: @HackerBoy Let me see if i could come up with solution

Comment: @HackerBoy You can use trick, duplicate your next slide and insert it in front of the one with the animation. And just apply animation to that slide with "After Previous" with delay option for 2 to 3 sec, so when your last object appear the duplicate slide will pop up itself after few second. Even though it's two slides and they look the same no one will be able to figure it out as it will look like automated. Its a bit longer process for lengthy PPT but hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the page, move the last "on click" animation over to that.
If it's a 2sec animation, set the animation to "with previous" and set the page to transition automatically after 2 seconds.

This way, when you click it jumps to the next page, the animation finishes and then it

Answer (score 0):

Animate show on a slide and then exit on the next.

```
Slide #1 - Enter Element A
Slide #2 - Exit Element A then Enter Element B
Slide #3 - Exit Element B then Enter Element C

etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyper link the "click to start" textbox to slide 2, so all elements play in loop unless the user clicks the " click to start" text.